# SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol PHP JSON GET API

Tags: json, api, get

Les comento, instala una aplicacion en un equipo de la red para administrar una UPS, podes acceder por IP para ver el estado ---> URL:https://10.64.1.69:8888/0/json  Tiene un GET JSON que te devuelve valores.

```html
{"key":"SAN MARTIN","device":{"key":"SAN MARTIN","id":0,"protocol":255,"portIndex":4,"status":"","ip":null,"upsIndex":0,"statusIcon":"online","hasWarn":false},"version":"","status":"Normal","model":"ON-LINE","warning":"","outFreq":"49.9Hz","inFreq":"49.9Hz","emdHumidity":"","batTemp":"","outVolt":"230.0V","noModule":false,"batCapacity":"100%","inVolt":"227.0V","bypassFreq":"49.9Hz","bypassVolt":"227.0V","oidType":0,"iStatus":0,"batTimeRemain":"2h1m0s","extStatus":0,"loadPercent":"10%","lsCounter":-1,"workMode":-1,"cfgBatNumber":"","emdAlarm1":"","emdAlarm2":"","emdTemp":"","abmState":"","cfgKVA":"","supportTest":true,"upsTemp":"21.8C","lastEvent2":"2023/07/27 08:13:13 Iniciar agente","statusColor":0,"lastEvent1":"","loadPercentMax":10,"loadSegment1State":"","loadSegment2State":"","redundantNumber":"","batV":"204.0V","outA":"2.6A","outVA":"0.6KVA","ls1":-1,"ls2":-1,"outW":"0.4KW"}
```

Pero recibo este erro ....  error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Les comparto el codigo que uso en la web para traer los datos !

```html
    <?php
    $url = "https://10.64.1.69:8888/0/json";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if($e=curl_error($curl)){
    echo $e;
}else{
    $json=json_decode($resp, true);

    $nbatV=$json['batV'];
    $nbatV    =$json['batV'];
}

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Tenemos un equipo de medicion de temperatura, y con el mismo codigo capturamos los datos y los mostramos en un web, el problema es que la UPS no adminite HTTP, hay que ingresar con HTTPS para que funcione.

Alguna solucion ?
Gracias!

Comment: Este sitio es en Español, prueba en el sitio en inglés.

Comment: Hola OCHOA ! lo paso a español !  haber si me podes dar una mano ! gracias !